# Powershell -searching thru eventlogs for a specific pattern

Tags: powershell

I am trying to research IIS service crashing. The eventlog I am trying to research has a very specific message: `World Wide Web Publishing Service service terminated unexpectedly`.

Im trying to list how many times this error message is listed in the systemlog.

I am trying with the following powershell commands but it's not really showing what Im trying to find:

```
> Id CommandLine                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  -- -----------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

   1 Get-EventLog System | Where-Object { $_.Message -match "W3SVC" }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   2 Get-EventLog System | Where-Object { $_.Message -match "IIS-IISReset" }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   3 Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Information -After 6/6/2010 -Source "Service Control Manager" | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 7034} | fl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   5 Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Information -After 6/6/2010 -Source "Service Control Manager" | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 7034} | Where-Object { $_.Message -match "IIS-IISReset" } | fl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   6 Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Information -After 6/6/2010 -Source "Service Control Manager" | Where-Object { $_.Message -match "World Wide Web Publishing Service service terminated unexpectedly" } | fl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   7 Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Information -After 6/6/2010 -Source "Service Control Manager" | Where-Object { $_.Message -contains "World Wide Web Publishing Service service terminated unexpectedly" } | fl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   8 Get-EventLog System | Where-Object { $_.Message -pattern "unexpectatedly" }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   9 Get-EventLog System | Where-Object { $_.Message -contains "unexpectatedly" }
```

Can you guys please specify a few commands that can work.

Thanks.

Comment: `Get-EventLog System |  Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 7034}` (note the underscore in `$_.EventID`) returns an array (you can check `.Count` property).

Comment: thank you, can you please elaborate on the .count powershell as well

Comment: This is giving all error msgs from event 7034; i am only looking for: World Wide Web Publishing Service service terminated unexpectedly. - thnx

Comment: Maybe `Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 7034 -and $_.Message -match 'World Wide Web Publishing Service'}`? In any case, I'd check `(Get-EventLog System | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 7034}).Message`

Comment: if the message is the same then just pipe to 'group-object'